# Getting variable from success function ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, variables

I have a variable in the success part of ajax and I want to reuse it in another function (which executed every 3 seconds), I tried to declare it global, but it does not work; Tdata is not known.
I know that $.ajax is an asynchronous function and I saw some posts similar to mine but it did not help me.

Help me please. Thank you.

This is a part of my code:

```
<script language='Javascript'> 
var Tdata;


$.ajax({
            method : "GET",
            url: "load-data.php",
            success : function(data){
                Tdata=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                          ////
            }

});

window.setInterval(function() { 

    $(window).load(function() {

                $.each(Tdata, function(variable) {  
                /////////////
                });

    }); 

}, 3000);


</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem with current code? do you get Tdata same every time? or is there some other problem?

Comment: No I can't, Tdata is not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
<script language='Javascript'> 
var Tdata;


$.ajax({
            method : "GET",
            url: "load-data.php",
            success : function(data){
                Tdata=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                          ////
            }

});

 $(window).load(function() {
window.setInterval(function() { 



                $.each(Tdata, function(variable) {  
                /////////////
                });



}, 3000);
 }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not wait until the AJAX request has successfully returned data before starting your interval? Since any executions of the interval's function aren't going to do anything (due to no data) before that point waiting isn't going to change the way the page would function in any way.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "load-data.php",
    dataType: "json"
    success: function(data) {
        var Tdata = data;
        // do some more stuff with the response of the AJAX request
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $.each(Tdata, function(variable) {  
                // do something with variable
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Note that I've removed the binding of the `load` event to the window every time the interval runs because doing so really doesn't seem to make any sense. I've also added a `dataType` property with a value of `json` to the options object passed to `$.ajax()` so you don't have to parse the response as JSON yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Function that uses the variable from AJAX call should be called from inside AJAX success, like this:

```
$.ajax({
        method : "GET",
        url: "load-data.php",
        success : function(data){
            Tdata=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            myFunction();
        }
});

function myFunction(){
        var interval = setInterval(function() { 
                $.each(Tdata, function(variable) {  
                /////////////
                });
        }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is callback tdataAjax function ajax success method run; @param parseJSON

```
var tdataAjax = function(callback) {

    $.ajax({
        method : "GET",
        url: "load-data.php",
        success : function(data){

            var Tdata=jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            setInterval(function() { 

                callback(Tdata);
            }, 3000);

       }

    });
};
```

is Callback function @param data in tdataAjax function

```
tdataAjax(function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(variable) { 

            // code
        });
});
```

tdataAjax ++ :)

```
 tdataAjax(function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(variable) { 

            // cla bla
        });
});
```